# ¿Porque mi fuente no se ve igual en todos los navegadores?

Tags: css, html5, fuentes

Estoy haciendo uso de CSS para utilizar mi fuente Lettera, al llevar mi desarrollo web a producción algunos navegadores no ven el mismo estilo de fuente, las siguientes son las definiciones que estoy utilizando en mi archivo CSS:

```css
.parrafoVerde {
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 3vmin;
    position: center;
    font-family: Lettera Text Std;
}

.IndustriaTexto {
    padding: 15px;
    /* font-size: 3vmin; */
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-family: Lettera Text Std;
}
```

```html
<p class="parrafoVerde">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit praesent, malesuada faucibus morbi litora nisi torquent pellentesque, integer facilisi nec maecenas cras nullam montes. 
<p />   

<p class="IndustriaTexto MoverNuestrasOperacionesIzquierda" >
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit praesent, malesuada faucibus morbi litora nisi torquent pellentesque, integer facilisi nec maecenas cras nullam montes. 
</p>
```

Adicional a esto estoy guardando la familia de mi fuente en una ubicación en una carpeta dentro del proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el problema persiste en que la fuente no se esta tomando desde los demás navegadores, incluso utilizando el mismo navegador siendo Chrome.

Al parecer me doy cuenta de que esto sucede al no tener instalada la fuente que estoy usando en los diferentes equipos.

**Actualización:**

Seguí la [guía](https://www.pagecloud.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-any-website) que recomendó @DavElsanto, pero aun no encuentro una solución, lo que he realizado hasta el momento es lo siguiente como dice la guía:

- Tengo mi fuente en formato **.OTF** la cual posteriormente cargue en [Webfont Generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) para crear mi Web Font Kit.
- Genere mi Web Font Kit en extensiones **.TTF** **.WOFF** **.SVG** **.WOFF2**
- Copie en hoja de estilos el CSS generado en el Web Font Kit, este lo pegue de la siguiente manera:

Adicional a las fuentes que genere en el Web Font Kit añadí a mi CSS el `font-face` de mi fuente en formato **.OTF**, pero aun no me soluciona.

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'Lettera Text Std';
        src: url('Font/LetteraTextStd.woff2') format('woff2'), 
            url('Font/LetteraTextStd.woff') format('woff'), 
            url('Font/LetteraTextStd.ttf') format('truetype'), 
            url('Font/LetteraTextStd.svg#LetteraTextStd') format('svg'),
            url('Font/LetteraTextStd-Títulos.otf') format('embedded-opentype');       
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        font-display: swap;
    }
```

**Actualización 2:**

Después de agregar todas los posibles formatos de fuentes para las diferentes versiones de navegador están de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualización 3:**

Al revisar la consola si sale un error, obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Usas `@font-face` o solo fuentes predeterminadas?

Comment: Pueda que aveces la fuente se quede en cache, sin embargo la importacion de la fuete no agregas y el nombre de las fuentes son diferentes.

Comment: Aca una guia de como debes importar tu fuente https://www.pagecloud.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-any-website

Comment: El paso 4 de la [guía que mencionas](https://www.pagecloud.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-any-website#c8b5a71a-bd64-4441-a34b-de78d488435c) habla de usar rutas absolutas para el origen de la fuente. Adicionalmente, los nombres de fuente que incluyen espacios, deberían estar [encerradas entre comillas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/font-family#ejemplos).

Comment: @Triby Revisa mi segunda actualización, así tengo el nombre de mis fuentes en mi ubicación, estoy haciendo algo mal con la ruta ? o el nombre ?

Comment: Por favor me confirmas si al momento de cargar la página en consola no te sale algún error relacionado con que la fuente no se puede cargar? Por favor preferible que no dejes espacios en los nombres de las fuentes, quiero decir, ni en el archivo, ni en el font-face {font-family:SinEspacios}. También puedes hacer la prueba solo cargando el formato ttf y te agradezco si lo que es código lo estructures bien en tu pregunta. Gracias

Comment: @MiguelAngelGonzalezPinto Es correcto, estoy obteniendo un error con una de las fuentes, alguna solución ? Revisa mi ultima actualización.

Comment: @JohnDoe Me parece ver que hay un espacio en el nombre del archivo entre "Lettera" y "Text..." Por favor verifícalo y confirma que lo estés cargando con el nombre correcto. Por otro lado efectivamente no está encontrando la fuente, por eso no se visualiza en la página web. Me puedes dejar ver por favor la estructura completa de carpetas y el path del archivo css desde dónde se llama la fuente. Fuera de eso, por favor formatear bien el código css que está en la pregunta.

Comment: @MiguelAngelGonzalezPinto El quitar la ruta de la fuente en formato .woff2 soluciono mi problema de que se ve la fuente anterior y luego cambia a la actual, que problema me puede traer esto a futuro ?

Comment: @JohnDoe No te debería traer problema alguno, ya que los otros formatos que cargas son compatibles con todos los navegadores (Normalmente yo uso ttf), y todo esto se carga desde el lado del cliente, así que una vez se haga la solicitud a la url, esta sencillamente carga todo el contenido, así como las fuentes incluidas en el proyecto. Ya entiendo tu otro problema. Mientras se carga la página y todo su contenido, incluyendo fuentes, puedes tener el problema que la fuente se demore en cargar y el resto de contenido ya lo haya hecho, por ello visualizas un texto diferente al deseado.

Comment: Para ello utiliza font-display, lo cual te permite solventar de alguna manera este inconveniente mientras terminas de cargar la fuente en la página. Te dejo el link https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probablemente solo sea un problema de rutas o definición de la fuente. Hice una prueba en local que funciona en Firefox, Chrome, Opera y Edge (basado en Chromium):

1. Descargué los archivos desde [onlinewebfonts](https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/download/6cc715122c2880c53facde0e44b3498c), solo formatos OTF, TTF y WOFF
2. Creé un documento HTML en la misma carpeta donde descargué las fuentes
3. En estilos CSS, primero declaro la fuente:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Lettera Text Std";
  src: url("LetteraTextStd.otf"),
    url("LetteraTextStd.ttf"),
    url("LetteraTextStd.woff");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap; 
}
```

Tanto el HTML, CSS y fuentes están en la misma carpeta, por eso es que no coloco rutas en `url("nombreDeArchivo.ext")`, en tu caso, debes especificar la carpeta de acuerdo a donde defines las reglas CSS, por ejemplo:

```
- Carpeta Raíz
  - CSS
      - Font
      - tu-archivo-de-estilos.css
```

En este caso, la carpeta `Font` está dentro de `CSS` y el archivo de estilos en el mismo nivel; debes definir la ruta con `url("Font/nombreDeArchivo.ext")`

Pero, si la estructura de directorios es diferente, algo como:

```
- Carpeta Raíz
  - CSS
      - tu-archivo-de-estilos.css
  - Font
```

La carpeta `Font` está al mismo nivel de `CSS` y el archivo de estilos en un nivel diferente de la fuente; debes hacer un paso atrás `../` para poder acceder: `url("../Font/nombreDeArchivo.ext")`

4. Aplicar estilos en el selector deseado:

```
/* Si quieres usarlo en todo el documento */
body {
  font-family:"Lettera Text Std", Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
/* Aplicar solo a un elemento por ID */
#id-de-contenedor {
  font-family:"Lettera Text Std", Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
/* Aplicar a múltiples elementos por clase */
.clase-de-elementos {
  font-family:"Lettera Text Std", Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/font-family), es conveniente definir la fuente que deseas y, separadas por coma, otras fuentes similares por si no se pudo descargar y aplicar la principal.

**¿Sigues con problemas?**

Probablemente es porque quieres cargar estilos adicionales usando la misma regla y, para efectos prácticos, pueden ser considerados como diferentes fuentes, entonces, para cargar la fuente de títulos debes hacerlo aparte:

```
@font-face {
  /* El nombre que aparece al abrir alguno de los archivos */
  font-family: "Lettera Text Std - Títulos";
  src: url("LetteraTextStd-Titulos.otf"),
    url("LetteraTextStd-Titulos.ttf"),
    url("LetteraTextStd-Titulos.woff");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap; 
}
/* Aplicar a múltiples elementos por etiqueta */
h1, h2, h3 {
  font-family:"Lettera Text Std - Títulos", Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

Solo recuerda, primero carga todas las fuentes y después crea las reglas para aplicarlas.

[image: Nombre de fuente en el archivo]

### Actualización:

Para tratar de evitar que se note el cambio de fuente al cargar la página, puedes intentar [precargar contenido](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content)

El primer problema es que tienes varios archivos de fuentes a cargar y deberás crear una etiqueta para cada uno de ellos como se sugiere [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content#cors-enabled_fetches):

```
<link rel="preload" href="fonts/cicle_fina-webfont.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
```

Tu código va a quedar con muchas líneas para precarga de fuentes y podría no ser tan fácil de mantener.

Te sugiero crear un archivo CSS específico para las fuentes y sea es el que agregues como contenido precargado:

```
<link rel="preload" href="Css/fuentes.css" as="style">
```

Comment: Hay alguna forma de controlar como se carga la fuente desde el navegador, al parecer la respuesta puede solucionar mi problema pero tengo el problema que se ve la fuente anterior y rápidamente cambia a la nueva, esto sucede al ingresar a las diferentes vistas de dicha pagina.

Comment: No, no hay manera, así es como trabajan los navegadores, mostrando primero alguna de las fuentes disponibles y cambiando cuando se completa la descarga de la personalizada. En ocasiones no es visible el cambio porque la fuente se descarga muy rápido.

Comment: Otra forma de cargar mi fuente personalizada que no sea `@font-face` y que no afecte el renderizado de la misma ?

Comment: @JohnDoe, de acuerdo a lo que te comentaron en otra pregunta, actualicé la respuesta para que pruebes opciones que carguen la fuente previamente y evitar ese "salto" al renderizar la página.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta importar tu fuente con font-face, haz lo siguiente al inicio de tu CSS:

```
@font-face {
        font-family: Lettera Text Std;
        src: url('Font/LetteraTextStd-bold.otf'),
             url('Font/LetteraTextStd-Titulos.otf');
    }
```

con eso debería funcionar, saludos!

Comment: Al agregar `@font-face` requiero cambiar algo en mi CSS, por ejemplo las clase que ya tengo creadas quitarles el `font-family: Lettera Text Std`

Comment: Seguí tu respuesta, pero aun sin solución

Comment: @JohnDoe no es necesario que le quites eso a tus clases, solo añade ese código al principio de tu CSS

Comment: @RimuruTempest Fue lo que hice pero aun no consigo una solución, puedes verlo en mis actualizaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Si ya tienes comprobado que las rutas de las fuentes son correctas, intenta hacer unos pequeños cambios de sintaxis.

Primero evita iniciar los nombres de las Clases y IDs con mayúsculas:

Cambia **.IndustriaTexto** por **.industriaTexto**  (recuerda hacerlo en el css y el html respectivamente)

Luego agrega comillas a tu nombre de fuente:

```
.industriaTexto {
    padding: 15px;
    /* font-size: 3vmin; */
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-family: "Lettera Text Std"; /* con comillas */
}
```